Strip the beginning stuff from C preprocessor output
The C preprocessor outputs lines at the start like:
# 0 "<built-in>"
# 1 "/project/header.h"

How can I stop it from printing that stuff?

What compiler / preprocessor are you using?

If it's gcc, use the -P option. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html
